# perl: loop over function that returns array or undef

Tags: perl

I am looking for the proper perl-ism for this issue.  I can work around it but just have to ask...

I am using HTML::TreeBuilder and am using the `look_down` method.  This returns an array or scalar depending on context and returns `undef` if no matching tag is found.  Cool.

I want to do the following:

```
foreach my $tag ( @{ $head->look_down('_tag', 'link') } ) {
    ...
}
```

but if there is no `link` tag the function returns `undef` and generates the error `Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at myCGI.cgi line ###`.  So I try this modification:

```
foreach my $tag ( @{ $head->look_down('_tag', 'link') || [] } ) {
    ...
}
```

My thought was that if the method returns `undef` then it will get changed into an empty array.  This works when there are no `link` tags.  But, if there is at least one expected tag then there is an error: `Not an ARRAY reference at myCGI.cgi line ###`.

Do I need to just bite the bullet and break the method call out of the loop and check for `undef` before entering the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"returns an array" is sometimes mentioned in documentation but is incorrect; perl subroutines always return lists (though in scalar context it will be a list with only one element).

It does *not* return undef in list context, it returns an empty list (`return` with no arguments returns an empty list in list context and undef in scalar context).  You can just loop over the returned values with no `@{ }` required:

```
foreach my $tag ( $head->look_down('_tag', 'link') ) {
    ...
}
```